# The error : No module named 'apscheduler.schedulers'

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have touch a error "No module named 'apscheduler.schedulers'" when i use the apscheduler.See the follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWtaK.png)

I'm so doubt,because i have tried three versions of apschedule:2.1.2,2.1.2,3.3.1(lastest),but it's still wrong.This is my first question on stackoverflow,thanks for your help!

Comment: Paste your error message as text, not an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be victim of a common Python pitfall. Just rename your file to something not used by a library, and you will be fine.

If you want to read more about it, here is an article detailling what's going on: http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2013/06/python-module-naming-pitfall/

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the python file you use is also called apscheduler.py.

Possibly the importer is getting confused and uses apscheduler.py as startpoint for importing 'apscheduler.schedulers'. Rename your python script and try again (make sure there is no apscheduler.py file anymore).